# For every $a, b, x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a \le x \le b$, we have $|x| \le \max\{|a| , |b|\}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, absolute-value

I was given an assigmnent in my Infintesiaml math course, and I'm having trouble proving the statement below:

For every $a, b, x  \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a \le x \le b$, we have $|x| \le \max\{|a| , |b|\}$

Hint: denote $r = \max \{|a| , |b|\}$.

Could it be false? I have tried using the triangle inequality, with and without the mentioned hint, and also tried isolating $x$ and $a$, or $x$ and $b$, but i think there is something important that I am missing.

I saw a similar question in a different post but the answers there are not explained very well.

Comment: I'd break things down by cases (according to whichever of the terms are $≥0$).

Comment: If you want to get it in one go (no cases) you can use $x=ta+(1-t)b$ with $t\in[0,1]$ and then $|a|\le \max(|a|,|b|)$ (same for $|b|$).

Comment: you could also do:
 
$ x \leq b \leq \lvert b \rvert \leq \max\{\lvert a \rvert, \lvert b \rvert\} $ 


and $ -x \leq -a \leq \lvert a \rvert \leq \max\{\lvert a \rvert, \lvert b \rvert\} $

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Remember  that for any $u$, $|u|=\max(u,-u)$. Therefore if $r=\max\bigl(|a|,|b|\bigr)$, we have $\;-r \le a,\,b,-a,-b\le r$. What can you deduce for $\max(x,-x)$?